# Crystal Reports Section Suppression not working

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-formulas

I have a report that is counting a specific event with a running total. In the group footer, I want to suppress the footer if the count is not a specific value `(RTotal0 <> 5)` AND if the most recent occurrence of the event is not within the last seven days `(datediff("d", EventDate, Currentdate) >7)`.

Either of these conditions works by themselves, but if I combine using an "AND" statement, only the datediff condition is evaluated; the RTotal condition is ignored. Any ideas? Here's my suppression formula:

```
{#RTotal0}<>5 and  DateDiff ("d",{EVENT-DATE},CurrentDate) >7
```

Thanks

Comment: Something that may help you troubleshoot this would be to create two new Formula Fields.  Set the first one to the value of your RTotal0 field and the other one will be the DateDiff Formula.  Then place both of these Formula Fields into the section you want to suppress based on there values.  This will at least help you confirm if they have the expected values at runtime that would allow the aggregated formula to function.

Answer (score 1):

Found this format finally worked:

```
not ({#RTotal0}=5 and DateDiff ("d",{EVENT-DATE},CurrentDate) <8 )
```

Comment: good to learn your self